# My app crashes when I click the buttons on MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, crash, android-viewbinding

I'm new to android development. Trying to practice some stuff I learnt on android developers by creating an app that displays two buttons on the mainactivity, the two buttons, on click, should launch a "studyActivity" and a "testActivity" respectively that displays a list of study/test cards with a viewHolder.

The app crashes when i click either of the two buttons I don't know where the problem is coming from.
It builds without an error.

Here's the MainActivity

```
package com.r.cxrslides

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.r.cxrslides.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var listIntent: Intent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Setup view binding
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Launch the StudyActivity on verticalBtn click
        binding.studyBtn.setOnClickListener {
            listIntent = Intent(this, StudyActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(listIntent)
        }

        // Launch the TestActivity on horizontalBtn click
        binding.testBtn.setOnClickListener {
            listIntent = Intent(this, TestActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(listIntent)
        }

    }

}
```

one of the classes the button click is supposed to launch

```
package com.r.cxrslides

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import com.r.cxrslides.adapter.SlideAdapter
import com.r.cxrslides.data.Datasource
import com.r.cxrslides.databinding.ActivityStudyBinding

class StudyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        
        val binding = ActivityStudyBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
       
        val myDataset = Datasource.slides
        
        val recyclerView = binding.studyRecyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = SlideAdapter(this, myDataset)

        binding.studyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        // Enable up button for backward navigation
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

      
    }
}
```

I used Intent, but the app keeps crashing when i click on the buttons.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: Without having the error displayed in the console it is complicated to answer you. Random: When you create a new Activity you have to declare it in the manifest. Is it done ?

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare I should have done that. It appears The image I was trying to use was too large. I changed it and it worked

Comment: Thank you @Ben I haven't learned anything about declaring new activities in the AndroidManifest yet. I just googled it and included declaration for the new activities. It works now. Still have a lot to learn. Thank you